# How to invoke onBackPressedDispatcher?.onBackPressed() from the fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, onbackpressed

I am a little stuck in the implementation of `onBackPressedDispatcher?.onBackPressed()` in the fragment

I have an Activity and Fragment within

I have a flow in the Fragment -> when a user clicks back button I need to show a dialog where it asks "Are you sure?" and once a user clicks "Yes" I have to go back.

So, in order to do so I did in my Fragment ->

```
...
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val callback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                showAlertDialog(
                    message = getString(R.string.myText),
                    dialogCallback = object : AlertDialogInterface {
                        override fun onAlertDialogButtonClicked(alertDialog: AlertDialog?) {}

                        override fun onPositiveButtonClicked(alertDialog: AlertDialog?) {
                            isEnabled = false
                            alertDialog?.dismiss()
                            activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.onBackPressed()
                        }

                        override fun onNegativeButtonClicked(alertDialog: AlertDialog?) {
                            alertDialog?.dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                    )
            }
        }

        activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(
            this,
            callback
        )
    }
...
```

So, I assume that once a user clicks "Yes" on the dialog it triggers this event `onPositiveButtonClicked` and in order to pass this event further I invoke this line -> `activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.onBackPressed()`, but it goes in a circle instead.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you had a button in your fragment to go back, what would you write in your onClick there? `parentFragmentManager.popBackStack()`? `findNavController.popBackStack()`? Why aren't you calling _that_ when your Yes button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it has been solved like this:

```
override fun onPositiveButtonClicked(alertDialog: AlertDialog?) {
    isEnabled = false
    alertDialog?.dismiss()
    callback.remove()
    activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.onBackPressed()
}
```

Once the callback is not needed, it could be removed